# background image radio button

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

Would it be possible give each radio button its own background image using jQuery? What I mean is:

[image: Example image]

```
<form id="tiepspiel" name="tiepspiel" action="#" method="POST">
        <ul id="sortable">
        <?php
        $count = 5;
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= $count) {
            echo '<li><ul class="elements">
        <li class="selectable">
            <label class="stein"><input type="radio" name="selected__'.$i.'" value="stein</label>
            <span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="selectable">
            <label class="schere"><input type="radio" name="selected_'.$i.'" value="schere"></label>
            <span></span>
        </li>
        <li class="selectable">
            <label class="papier"><input type="radio" name="selected_'.$i.'" value="papier"></label>
            <span></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
                    </li>';
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
        <hr>
        <button>Submit</button>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

and I'm trying to add CSS to each class. For example:

```css
.papier {
    background-image: url("../images/papier_blue.png");
    width: 82px;
    height: 82px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Why using jQuery? And what have you tried?

Comment: okay I have been adding some of a code. Surprise me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background images don't work so well with the radio buttons themselves. What you can do is wrap them each in a `<label>` as follows:

```
<ul class="elements">
    <li class="selectable">
        <label class="stein"><input type="radio" name="stein" value="stein"></label>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="selectable">
        <label class="schere"><input type="radio" name="schere" value="schere"></label>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="selectable">
        <label class="papier"><input type="radio" name="papier" value="papier"></label>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then, your CSS should work as-is.

Comment: sorry to tell but I'm not even close with this workaround

Comment: @fefe: So... anything more for me to go on, or just "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @fefe: You'll need a `display: inline-block;` on things too, by the way.

Comment: label would be my preferred method but you can add padding and background images to radios. The problem, as you say, is it needs display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

You put the background styles on the wrong class. Put them in your `.selectable` class definition.

Comment: thank you I'm going to give a try

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a kind of "fake radio button". There are many ways to do this, including jquery, or you can easly do it with css. 
As somebody told, you have to wrap the radio button with a `span` or `label`. By default they are not 'block' elements, like 'div', so you can't obtain your result unless you will not attribute this ( display:block; or display:inline-block; ). Also don't forget to set the width and the height ( i mean to span/label ) and also set opacity 0 to the radio button. 
I recommend to you to have a look at http://ajaxian.com/archives/custom-css-inputs or you can also have a look inside http://www.iamntz.com/625/frontend-developer/formulare-custom-checkbox-radio-v-2/ ( nevermind if it is in romanian, you only check demo and have a look to the code )

There is no rocket-science, you only have to take care of some stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are right. There hundereds of way to do this and maybe the workaround what I took is not the proper one. Before I was taking look on jquery ui's radio buttons solution and that's why I thought maybe could point me to a solution. The problem with radio buttons that I can not hide properly

Comment: Add your current code to http://jsfiddle.net/ and i'm sure you will find an aswer in a very short time